# Using GORM and Postgresql how to set the search_path?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

How can I get the current schema from gorm?  Normally it is "SHOW search_path" and is an exec.  Same with setting the current search_path  normally "set search_path to newschema". where new schema can be a single schema name of a series of names.

I attempted db.Exec("show search_path").Find(&result) where result is a []string and I get an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND how to display current schema by experimenting and a hint about Raw and Scan in PluralSite's GORM class.

```
var currentSchema string
rows, err := db.Debug().Raw("show search_path").Rows()
rows.Next()  // to get the first and only result
rows.Scan(&currentSchema)
fmt.Printf("Search Path: %v\n", currentSchema)
```

returns: Search Path: "$user", public

Taking @PavloStrokov point about transactions (which are basically threads and a transaction) into account, I was able to get the schema to stay during the current process. In the handler, I use the existing DB connection and create a transaction. It gets passed to every method that is called that touches the Database. I change the call to the gorm method to be the passed tx instead of the normal db variable that was stored and made available to any method that needed it.

The call I make to start it all of is:

tx := db.Begin()

tx.Exec("set search_path to schema_name")

The string is generated to use the proper Facility schema name.

The tx is the last param in the signature of all methods that touch the DB. For example func methiodUsingDBSchema(val1 string, val2 string,  tx *gorm.DB){}

Then the last thing I do is tx.Commit()  Even though these are all reads.

I have run all test and works well.

I use the Postgres schemas to separate Facilities in my application and need to change based upon the user logged in.  All User and Facility information is in public.

Answer (score 5):

Setting `search_path` by executing query like `set search_path to newschema` is incorrect way of setting, because this will be changed only for the connection that was used to execute the query.

To set it to full set of connection that your application will use you need to provide `search_path` as an argument to `gorm.Open("postgres", "dbname=YourDB search_path=YourSearchPath")` with all other connection arguments you gonna to use like `dbname` or `port`, `user`, etc.

Comment: Changing for the current query IS what is needed. We look at the current user using the API and check their facility, then change the current schema to the proper one for their current facility. User can be at different facilities or accessing different facilities at any time.  This app was originally written in Rails using Apartments and has processed 100s of million API calls each one could be one of several facilities.

The on DB open is more expensive if have to do on every call or keep track of which process has which facility open.  It was tried several years ago and unacceptable.

Comment: @DonaldFrench than please execute it in the transaction, otherwise you could get into situation when you run `set` on one connection, but actual query will be run on the other with the old search_path. When you open transaction it sticks to to connection and you will be in safe.

Comment: @DonaldFrench if you find my comments useful, please click "arrow up". I want to reach 1k reputation :)