# GORM and PostgreSQL: search_path is used only when doing the first request

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm currently working on an api gateway that forwards requests to an grpc client. The routes use a middleware. Within that middleware the `Validate` function from the dialed grpc client is used. The function is in the last code snippet at the end.

The gateway is based on a gin router, which, as far as I understand handles each request in a separat go routine. I can send as many requests simultaneously to either to endpoint `/protected/1` or to endpoint `/protected/2` and they get handled correctly.

The `Validate` function is having problems handling request sent simultaneously to `/protected/1` and `/protected/2`. Sending two request to both endpoints simultaneously results in that either both, none or only one of the requests is handled correctly. The error message that I receive is actually from the gorm function trying to query the user in the `Validate` function (`ERROR: relation "users" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)`). I use a gorm database object that is connected to a postgres database. This behaviour suggests that some how a resource is shared. Using `run -race` does not give any insights.

So my questions are, why does this setup not work to send requests simultaneously to both endpoints?

I tried to make a working minimal example, but somehow I could nor reproduce the error in a minimal setting, hence I would like to share my code snippets here.

Important snippets of the the Api Gateway implementation

```
func main() {
  c, err := config.LoadConfig()
  ...
  r := gin.Default()
  auth.RegisterRoutes(r, &c)
  r.Run(":" + c.Port)
}
```

whereas the routes are defined as

```
func RegisterRoutes(r *gin.Engine, c *config.Config){
  svc := &ServiceClient{
    Client: InitServiceClient(c),
  }
  a := InitAuthMiddleware(svc)

  // routes
  protected := r.Group("/protected")
  protected.Use(a.AuthRequired)
  protected.GET("/1", svc.DoStuff)
  protected.GET("/2", svc.DoStuff)

}
// dummy handler
func (svc *ServiceClient) DoStuff(ctx *gin.Context) {
  handler.DoStuff(ctx, svc.Client)
}
```

The grpc client is dialed with the following function

```
type ServiceClient struct {
    Client pb.AuthServiceClient
}

func InitServiceClient(c *config.Config) pb.AuthServiceClient {
    // using WithInsecure() because no SSL running
    cc, err := grpc.Dial(c.AuthSvcUrl, grpc.WithInsecure())

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not connect:", err)
    }

    return pb.NewAuthServiceClient(cc)
}
```

and the middleware is implemented in the following way:

```
type AuthMiddlewareConfig struct {
    svc *ServiceClient
}

func InitAuthMiddleware(svc *ServiceClient) AuthMiddlewareConfig {
    return AuthMiddlewareConfig{svc}
}

func (c *AuthMiddlewareConfig) AuthRequired(ctx *gin.Context) {
    access_token, _ := ctx.Cookie("access_token")
    
    res, err := c.svc.Client.Validate(context.Background(), &pb.ValidateRequest{
        Token:     access_token,
        TokenType: "ACCESS_TOKEN",
        Url:       ctx.Request.URL.String(),
    })
   
    if err != nil || res.Status != http.StatusOK {
        ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"status": http.StatusUnauthorized, "error": res.Error})
        return
    }

    ctx.Set("userId", res.UserId)

    ctx.Next()
}
```

Important snippets of the Auth Service:

```
func serve(c *conf.Configuration) {
    /* 
      Dial returns:
      type Repository struct {
        DB *gorm.DB
       }
    */
    h := storage.Dial(&c.DB)

    serviceUri := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", c.API.Port)

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", serviceUri)

    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal("Failed to listen on: ", err)
    }

    s := api.Server{
      R:   h,
      //
    } 

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterAuthServiceServer(grpcServer, &s)

    if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalln("Failed to serve:", err)
    }
}
```

and the validate function is implemented by

```
type Server struct {
    R   storage.Repository
    //
    // #https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3794:
    pb.UnimplementedAuthServiceServer
}

func (s *Server) Validate(ctx context.Context, req *pb.ValidateRequest) (*pb.ValidateResponse, error) {
     // token validation stuff works

    var user models.User

    // causes error sometimes
    if result := s.R.DB.Where(&models.User{Id: claims.Id}).First(&user); result.Error != nil {
        return &pb.ValidateResponse{
            Status: http.StatusNotFound,
            Error:  "User not found",
        }, nil
    }

    // send response
}
```

**EDIT**

For completeness here the function that connects to the postgres client.

```
func openDb(c *conf.PostgresConfiguration, gormConfig *gorm.Config, database string) *gorm.DB {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s", c.User, c.Password, c.Host, c.Port, database)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(connectionString), gormConfig)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to connect to database '%s' given url: ", database), err)
    }
    logrus.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Connected to database %s", database))
    return db
}

func Dial(c *conf.PostgresConfiguration) Repository {
    gormDefaultConfig := &gorm.Config{}
    gormAppConfig := &gorm.Config{}

    // connect to default database
    logrus.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Use default database %s for initialization", c.DefaultDatabase))
    defaultDb := openDb(c, gormDefaultConfig, c.DefaultDatabase)

    // check if database exists and create it if necessary
    var dbexists bool
    dbSQL := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '%s') AS dbexists;", c.AppDatabase)
    defaultDb.Raw(dbSQL).Row().Scan(&dbexists)
    if !dbexists {
        logrus.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Created database %s", c.AppDatabase))
        db := defaultDb.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE DATABASE %s;", c.AppDatabase))
        if db.Error != nil {
            logrus.Fatal("Unable to create app database: ", db.Error)
        }
    }

    // connect to app databse
    appDb := openDb(c, gormAppConfig, c.AppDatabase)

    // check if schema exists and create it if necessary
    var schemaexists bool
    schemaSQL := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = '%s') AS schemaexisits;", c.AppDatabaseSchema)
    appDb.Raw(schemaSQL).Row().Scan(&schemaexists)
    // create app specfic database, if not already existing
    if !schemaexists {
        // create service specific schema
        db := appDb.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE SCHEMA %s;", c.AppDatabaseSchema))
        if db.Error != nil {
            logrus.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to create database schema %s", c.AppDatabaseSchema), db.Error)
        }
        logrus.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Created database schema %s", c.AppDatabaseSchema))
    }

    db := appDb.Exec(fmt.Sprintf(`set search_path='%s';`, c.AppDatabaseSchema))
    logrus.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Use existing database schema %s", c.AppDatabaseSchema))
    if db.Error != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to set search_path for database to schema %s", c.AppDatabaseSchema), db.Error)
    }

    // migrate table
    appDb.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})

    return Repository{appDb}
}
```

**Edit2**

Changing the connection string in the `openDb` function to `connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?search_path=%s", c.User, c.Password, c.Host, c.Port, database, c.AppDatabaseSchema)` fixes the issue (see how the search_path is part of the url).
Thank you!

Comment: «relation "users" does not exist»—to me, this sounds like whichever request gets served first, actually populates (initializes) the database, and the following request, if manage to get through fast, hit the condition of a half-populated DB. Before we discuss ways to fix that, could you either prove or disprove my guess?

Comment: I don't see why this should not be "thread safe". You don't show what database client you are using but usually those are concurrency safe. And databases itself are usually also concurrency safe. Btw in your middleware, you probably should pass the request context rather than context.Background-

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to run your migrations? Maybe this has nothing to do with concurrency but your database is simply not properly initialized. When you dont use the validate middleware, you never see it because you never try to query a user. At least thats what the error looks to me. Its simply telling your that some table is missing.

Comment: @kostix good catch. I checked that the Dial function is only called once in the serve function as it should be. So the Repository with the pointer to the initialised  `DB *gorm.DB` should then be used for all subsequent requests. Am I missing something? I added also the Dial function which is used to connect to the postgres client.

Comment: @TheFool thanks for the response. I changed the background, same outcome. Seems you are as puzzled as I am why this isn't concurrency safe as it should be.

Comment: @TheFool I have multiple endpoints, register, login, ... all these endpoints don't use the middleware, but query the database accordingly. While hitting these endpoints the database can always be queried. So The database is initialized. I can connect to the postgres client and query the user table.

Comment: I am not such much puzzled. I am more in doubt that your assessment is correct. From the information provided, nothing indicates that this has something to do with concurrency. The error indicates an error with your schema or query syntax. [see this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050906045207.GA95353@winnie.fuhr.org), for example.  Imo the question does not contain enough debugging information in order to give an answer. From what you show, there is no problem.

Comment: Consider creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kostix you are right! Only the first request has the correct `search_path` set. In the `Dial` function I set the `search_path`. But apparently this option is only set for the first request. I don't see yet why. But adding the line `s.R.DB.Exec(fmt.Sprintf(`set search_path='%s';`, "auth"))` before the query in the `Validate` function fixes the issue. So the question is how is the search path permanently set to a specific schema in the Dial function?

Comment: @TheFool thank you for your answer. I guess I figured out where the issue is coming from. It has indeed nothing todo with concurrency, but the issue is somehow in the Dial function and how the schema is set. see previous comment.

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/) `search_path`? Well, and which PostgreSQL driver you're using in your code?

Comment: yes this `search_path`. I use GORM and the underlying driver is pgx according to [this](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html). See my edit, this fixes the issue. But I still don't know what went wrong initially.

Comment: The first three results of [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+gorm+search_path) to a popular internet search engine look interesting. I'd dig deeper. For instance, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56368340/720999), and [this](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3975).